# Patter Regex for SlashA-ZSlash

Tags: regex

I need a Regex patter to Validate /A-Za-z/.

I want the pattern to have a forward slash required at the start and end of the characters.  Ex: /John Doe/

Comment: What's the problem? Put slashes in the pattern. If you're using `/` as the pattern delimiter, escape them.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated- the problem is I don't know how to write the regular expression to enforce this rule.

Comment: Check if the answer I wrote can help you with it

Comment: @MilesBodzin If you want to learn RegEx I recommend you https://regexone.com/ it is free and very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^\/[A-Za-z ]+\/$` to match starting and ending slashes in your text.

Comment: Why do you have space in the character set?

Comment: If he wants to match names such as his example `/John Doe/` the _space_ is needed

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

`^[\/][a-zA-Z\s]+[\/]$` -
Matches your requirements and just that from what you have said
Test [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/GOPrYU/1)

`^[\/][a-zA-Z]*[\s]?[a-zA-Z]*[\/]$` - This one only matches if there is one or no space in the middle of two words any length
Test [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/GOPrYU/3)